# How can my plugin generate a generic modal window in the Control Panel?

Tags: plugin-development, control-panel, fieldtypes, modal, garnish

I'm working on a plugin, and it requires a modal to be displayed when the user interacts with a field of my Field Type. When the user finishes interacting with the modal, they would click "Done".

This is the standard modal that displays when you select Assets...

[image: Assets Modal]

I basically want a more generic version of this modal, where I can put anything I want into the middle of it.

**I would love to have something like this:**

[image: Blank Modal]

**What's the best way to pull that off?**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Create a div with whatever contents you want in the modal, and with a class "modal". Then create a new [Garnish.Modal](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/lib/garnishjs/garnish.js) object with it:

```
var $div = $('<div class="modal">...</div>');
var myModal = new Garnish.Modal($div);
```

Comment: Shockingly simple and brilliantly effective... it's the Craft way. I'll have to play around with Garnish a little more to get exactly the behavior that I need, but this definitely puts me on the right track. Thanks Brandon, greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does the div need to be created in the jQuery object.  Or can you reference the div from your inputType template?

Comment: @aran Doesn’t matter how the div was created. But keep in mind that it if it’s already positioned in the DOM, passing it to a new Garnish.Modal() instance is going to yank it out of its current position.

Comment: That link to Modal.js should now be https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Garnish/blob/master/src/classes/Modal.js. I can't submit an edit as the change is less than 6 characters.