# Possible to override Garnish.Modal? [Plugin]

Tags: plugin-development, modal, garnish

Is there a way to override Garnish.Modal?

For example, I have a custom modal which uses a custom form but I want to be able to use the built in forms.elementSelect to select from a user list. When I select a user and press "select" it closes both my custom modal and my user select window.

**Can I override this to just close the most recent modal?**

This is in reference to Custom Modals inside Plugins: [How can my plugin generate a generic modal window in the Control Panel?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/374/45)

**Edit:** It looks as if Garnish hides any other modals before loading a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Garnish.Modal will automatically close other modals when [`show()`](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Garnish/blob/master/Source/classes/Modal.js#L91) is called (which happens automatically when you first create it).

That behavior can be overridden by setting the `closeOtherModals` setting to `false`, though:

```js
var myModal = new Garnish.Modal($container, {
    closeOtherModals: false
});
```

Comment: Thanks, problem is the forms.elementSelect (users) window is the one causing the conflict. I open my window, click add user and it opens the user select window and hides my orignal. So when I close user select, my 1st window is gone.

For now I'll probably just move this to another template and not to a modal.