# Recommended way to provide user feedback in the control panel?

Tags: plugin-development, modal

Is there a recommended way to provide user feedback in the control panel — something like a modal window with a simple 'ok' button to dismiss?

I am writing a plugin that syncs data between users, another channel ('accounts'), and an external service (Braintree), using saveEntry and saveUser events to create/update related records as needed. I would like to provide user feedback in the way of a modal window that reports what related records were created and/or updated. What would be the recommended 'Craft' way to implement this user feedback modal? Or is there something already built-in to support this and how might I access it? I see some advice here regarding [generating a generic modal window](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/374/how-can-my-plugin-generate-a-generic-modal-window-in-the-control-panel), but not sure the best way to integrate this within my plugin. Any advice would be appreciated even if very general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, this seems like a great use case for a custom [dashboard widget](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/widgets).

Comment: Are you thinking of a kind of a dashboard log? That's an interesting idea. Fyi, this is not being done in batches, I am simply tapping into the onSaveEntry to trigger the create/update on the other records. I'm currently throwing errors, using logs, and userSession->setNotice/setError. Not ideal but works ok.