# Is there an API for modals?

Tags: control-panel, user-interface

I’m looking to hook into existing modal functionality, if any exists.

Is there any way of doing this?

If there is, what’s the advised approach and considerations required to ensure responsiveness?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the CP you can generate a modal using craft's 'garnish' js as explained in [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/384/784). On the front-end I believe you would need to develop you own solution.